# How does a yogi creates a new physical body?

Tags: yoga, meditation

As I am going through [Autobiography of a Yogi Chapter -3 The Saint With Two Bodies](http://www.ananda.org/autobiography/#chap43)
 which is suggested by one of our SE fellow Bhrahmagnani in one of his comment to my question. Which tells about Swami Pranabananda, An Exalted Disciple of Lahiri Mahasaya. who has created two bodies by the grace of his guru.

My question:

- How does a yogi creates a new physical body? Was this happened with his karmic sharir? or something else?
- Was there anyone (except Swami Pranabananda), who also did the similar thing creating a new body of own?
- Is this possible to create a new body of others as Swami Pranabananda created his own?

Comment: Yes it is very much possible and happens regularly in the lives of saints and avatars. Upon reading the lives of Sri Rama, Sri Krishna, Paramahansa Yogananda, Swami Vivekananda, Sri Sathya Sai Baba, Sri Sai Baba of Shirdi, Sri Swami Sivananda, Sri Ramana Maharishi, Jesus Christ, etc. are filled with such incidents where they are seen in various different places at once. The Yogi is a master of the Universe. He has no limitations. However The One who has Realized Brahman, does not desire to 'show off' his powers to others. He only performs that which helps other people. All the best sir!!

Answer (score 3):

The method is detailed in Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms III. 39. and IV. 4.

In III. 39. it tells how a yogi and enter into another's body or even a dead body.

In his commentary on IV. 4. Swami Vivekananda explains how the verse tells how a yogi can create another body or a group of bodies (Kaya-vyuha) to exhaust karma quickly.

Comment: You shouldn't just say that it's described in these Sutras, you should explain what they say.

Comment: Swamiji, can you provide  authentic book of unabridged Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms online?

Comment: @AnilKumar Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms with original Devanagari script and Vivekananda's translation and commentary are here under the heading 'Raja Yoga' - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_1/vol_1_frame.htm