# Questions Re Yogi Making New Body

Tags: yoga, yogi

Am wondering, when a yogi makes a new body, where is his soul located, is it in the new body he made, or in his old body ? Or is it in both at the same time.

Cause making a new body is different from entering another body, or entering a dead body. Related to this thread on here :

[How does a yogi creates a new physical body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6760/how-does-a-yogi-creates-a-new-physical-body)

At high level supernatural abilities, could a yogi make a new body, enter that body, then just have his old body cremated ? So he physically just becomes a new guy but with same personality, same memories as before of course.

Edit : Another random question I have after trying to answer Amethyst question is this, could the new body made by the yogi be totally different than the old body ? Like a different gender, appearance, etc

Comment: Actually maybe this is sort of the same as the linked question above, if so plz let me know if I should delete this, no probs :)

Comment: Getting a new body by shedding the old body is called Kaya Kalpa. Some Yogis in the Himalayan region know the technique and by using it they live for many years.

Comment: @Rickross Hey friend, I have this post you made awhile back bookmarked on here cause I am so drawn to this kind of stuff : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32259/which-saints-or-yogis-from-history-are-recorded-to-have-done-parakaya-pravesha-s Ok so then I think obviously the soul totally transfers to the new body. I looked up the book you mention in the comments, Kalpataru Kamdhenu, but I don’t know Bengali yet. Even my Hindi sucks haha But one day when I know Bengali more I’ll try and read it. I want to learn all about this stuff. Gyanganj and other places like that are so cool :D

Comment: Thanks for your nice words. BTW note that Kayakalpa and Parakaya Pravesha are two different things. In the first your own old body gets shed and a new body is formed (in this soul remains within the body and does not go any where). In the second, one enters (that is the soul enters) the body of another person.

Comment: @Rickross Thx for clarifying, that makes sense. So in kayakalpa, the new body is just a much younger version of your own body then, no change in appearance otherwise. Whereas in Parkaya Pravesh the soul enters a totally different looking other body that can be dead or alive, like what AdiShankar and Rajah VikramAditya did (I think.)

Comment: Yes that is right .. also after doing Kayakalpa one looks much younger so some change in appearance takes place.

Comment: @Rickross Thx so much, I appreciate it, I think I’m clear on how these work now :D